# Cpp - Cannot open the file

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a simple problem with reading the file. I am trying to open a file which is included to the resource files as .txt file. The problem appear when I am trying to compile it and print it from the structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct mystruct
{
double x, y;
int a;

};


int main()
{
using namespace std;

ifstream file("file.txt");
double x, y;
int a;
if (file.is_open()) {
    while (file >> x >> y >> a)
    {
        mystruct m;
        m.x;
        m.y;
        m.a;

        cout << m.x << endl << m.y << endl << m.a << endl;
    }
}
else
    cout << "Cannot open the file";

return 0;
}
```

I am using that wired shifting because in my file I have three different values which I have to store for three different variables in my structure.

Why my file is not visible and cannot be opened?

Here is the link to file.txt source: http://wklej.org/hash/05290721372/

And also here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(reading_from_file)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(reading_from_file ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Maybe here is the problem why the file is not visible.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: sorry for my bad English.

Second: are you sure that file.txt is in the right directory?

And what about read permission? Try with

```
chmod ugo+r file.txt
```

To me it works; or, at least, it opens the file.

However, I do not think the program is working as you expect: it reads the values but prints, each time, the three random values which are inizialized in the members of 'm'.

You should change it this way

```
ifstream file("file.txt");
if (file.is_open()) {
   mystruct m;
   while (file >> m.x >> m.y >> m.a)
      cout << m.x << endl << m.y << endl << m.a << endl;
}
else
   cout << "Cannot open the file";
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. 
I really don't know why it doesn't want to open, but I will install Linux and put Windows to the bin in next few minutes. :)
Ps: permissions are fine

Comment: Fantastic idea. :)  
I'm kidding, of course.
And excuse me: I'm so used to Unix / Linux that I didn't think that your system could be without "chmod".